# How to use BugSnag inside of a nuxt.js app?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, bugsnag

[BugSnag](https://www.bugsnag.com/) provides a very useful and initially free product for tracking errors in your vue app. The problem is that there is no documentation for using this in a nuxt app. A plugin would be the best place to utilize it in the app.

Trying to resolve this was killing me for a while but I was able to find help from Patryk Padus from the comments on [this post](https://medium.com/@patryk_42447/for-me-was-better-that-code-as-plugins-bugsnag-js-57142f8721aa).

Answer (score 5):

For anyone trying to make this happen, do the following:

1.Place the following code inside of a plugin located in the /plugins folder of your application root:

```
#/plugins/bugsnag.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import bugsnag from '@bugsnag/js'
import bugsnagVue from '@bugsnag/plugin-vue'

const bugsnagClient = bugsnag({
  apiKey: 'YOUR-KEY',
  notifyReleaseStages: [ 'production', 'staging' ]
})

bugsnagClient.use(bugsnagVue, Vue);

export default (ctx, inject) => {
  inject('bugsnag', bugsnagClient)
}
```

2.Inside of the nuxt.config add the following to your plugins section:

```
plugins: [
  '@/plugins/bugsnag.js',
],
```

3.Inside of your vue layout reference the bugsnag object using the `$bugsnag` object:

```
this.$bugsnag.notify(new Error('Nuxt Test error'))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're reading this in January 2021 and using Nuxt v2.x.x and above, the above answer might not work for you.

Here's what I did instead:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import bugsnag from '@bugsnag/js'
import BugsnagVue from '@bugsnag/plugin-vue'

const bugsnagClient = bugsnag.start({
  apiKey: process.env.BUGSNAG_KEY,
  plugins: [new BugsnagVue()], // this is important
})

Vue.use(bugsnagClient) // // this is also important

export default (ctx, inject) => {
  inject('bugsnag', bugsnagClient)
}
```

> Tip: Install the @nuxt/dotenv module to be able to use `process.env` in your plugin.

References:

[Bugsnag Vue installation reference](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/javascript/vue/#installation)